How to have pyautogui detect a specific color?
Trying to have pyautogui detect color of a certain pixel but it keeps saying the color is there even when it isn't.
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
import win32com.client as comclt
while 1:
    try:
        pyautogui.pixel(1400,545)[1] == 213
        time.sleep(5)
        print ("I can see it!")
        time.sleep(10)
    except ImageNotFoundException:
        print ("No")

I tried "pyautogui.pixel" but's that's not working.

You are checking for the color, but the result of this comparison is not used:
pyautogui.pixel(1400,545)[1] == 213

This line will evaluate to False if the color mismatches, but will not raise an exception such as ImageNotFoundException.
You can use an if statement to evaluate the color correctness:
while True:
    if pyautogui.pixel(1400,545)[1] == 213:
        print ("I can see it!")
    else:
        print ("No")
    time.sleep(1)

